# What is the difference between tenant and user?

Tags: cloud

I am currently start to learn about multi tenancy , but it is complex. Before understanding multi tenancy i decide to understand difference between tenant and user.

Comment: Many users may belong to the same tenant. Imagine you have a SaaS and you have 3 clients (companies) and each one has many users. It depends on the case, but each client could be a tenant (3 in total), while the users could have different roles inside the same tenant.

Comment: is privileges  different for each user in the tenant?

Comment: It could be, yes.

Comment: Thank you Hector

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a supermarket (tenant) management software and buyers (users). You can code a software to manage a single supermarket and its buyers... but you can also decide to go multitenant:

Your software will be able manage multiple supermarkets (tenant) where buyers are registered too (or not...) depending if they are buying at this supermarket. In other words, a user consumes a tenant's services.

Globally, multi-tenancy aims to reduce costs, by aggregating data. More explanaitions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy).

Answer (score 0):

A tenant us a boundary around configuration and data. The view created by a tenant may be shared between many users.

For example, a tenant often represents legal ownership of the data - such as the organization responsible for the data. It shouldn't be possible for the data to leak between different tenants. They expect "hard walls" to protect their data. All users for a tenant-organization are likely to share this view of configuration and data (though there may be futher role-based restrictions, these restrictions would never move the boundary).

In some cases, the tenant appears to be an individual person. Your cloud backup is usually something you want kept separate from all other users. In practice, as soon as you share a file with someone else the concept of there being something bigger than a single user as the tenant is often still needed.

In specific contractual or legal situation, complete isolation is needed. This is costly as the infrastructure to manage a completely isolated instance is more costly than if you could share the infrastructure between many tenants. The idea is to achieve a higher "tenant density" to avoid paying for CPU, memory, network, and other resources that are sitting idle. This sharing is called "multi-tenancy".

It's also worth considering that a tenant might not be an organization. It could be something like a physical location (like a retail store, a clinic, etc) where you may want to run an application that can survive network disruptions, even if you sync the data to a central location when there is a network available. As the location has its own specific configuration and data, it may be viewed as a tenant.